# fluent-ffmpeg: can't use drawtext in complexFilters

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

I have the following fluent-ffmpeg code:

```
    await ffmpeg(url)
            .input("./watermark.png")
            .videoCodec("libx264")
            .audioCodec("aac")
            .toFormat("mp4")
            .complexFilter([
                "[0:v]pad=iw:2*trunc(iw*16/18):(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2 [resized]",
                "[1:v]scale=150:150 [watermark]",
                "[resized][watermark]overlay=W-w-100:100 [withwatermark]",
                "[withwatermark]drawtext=text='hello':fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:x=20:y=20 [output]",
            ])
            .outputOptions([
                "-map [output]",
                "-movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov",
                "-preset veryfast",
                "-crf 28",
            ])
            .output("./video.mp4", { end: true })
            .on("error", (err) => {
                throw err;
            })
            .run();
```

When I leave out the last complexFilter item, it works as espected. But it seems there is an error in my drawtext line, because I get the following error:

> Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Error initializing complex filters.
> Invalid argument

Can someone help me out?